# How does one affirm an appointment offered with 「どうですか？」?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example:

> さざいさんのスケジュールはどうですか？
>
> How is [the proposed time for] Sazai's (your) schedule?

The simple affirmation -- 「どうです」 -- seems wrong since 「どう」 is a question word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「ＯＫです。」
「それで良いです。」
「それで都合が良いです。」
「空いてます。大丈夫です。」　（あいてます）　×開いて

---

For NO : 　「いやー、残念なんですが・・・」　「あの、ちょっと都合が・・・」　「駄目です。」　「埋まってます。」　「もう決まってます。」 ........　When younger folks say 「ビミョー」（微妙）, it usually means No.

「大丈夫です。」 (by itself) has become problematic.　Younger folks sometimes use it to mean 「結構です」

> 若者の「大丈夫」の使い方がおかしい … あなたは「大丈夫」？ 〈AERA〉｜dot ... dot.asahi.com › AERA
>
> 2016/02/19 - 何だ、また乱れる若者言葉か、と単純な話でもないようで……。 東京・銀座でバーを ... 大丈夫じゃないらしい。ノー、の意味に使う若者が増えているというのだ。 ... 彼に任せておけば大丈夫だ」とか、転んだ人に「大丈夫ですか？」と声をかける ...

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your question alone, I don't think it is a yes-or-no question.

さざいさんのスケジュールはどうですか？
How is your schedule?

You cannot answer that question with a yes or no. 
You have to actually say when you are free.